# How to set value to textfield from get form in extjs

Tags: extjs4, textfield, setvalue

I have form

```js
xtype: 'form',
border: false,
padding: '5 0 0 0',
bodyPadding: 5,
items: [{
 xtype: 'textfield',
 fieldLabel: 'Theme Name',
 name: 'themeName',
 itemId: 'themeName',
 allowBlank: false
},{
 xtype: 'displayfield',
 fieldLabel: 'Text',
 itemId: 'themeText',
        name: 'Text',
 value: '<div class="theme-text-upload"></div>'
}]
```

Then I have function to set value to textfield.

```js
setValueToTextField: function(){
  var field = form.getForm();  
  for (var i = 0; i < field.items.length; i++) {      
 var name = field.items[i].name;
 var fieldData = data[name];
        if(field.items[i].xtype === 'textfield'){
            field.items[i].name.setValue(fieldData);
        }
  };
}
```

But I can not set value to textfield. It showed error message that setValue() is not a function.

Comment: Try field.items[i].setValue(fieldData); instead of field.items[i].name.setValue(fieldData);

Comment: I tried that but still cannot

Comment: wat are you trying to set in text field. What does data[name] signifies?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not give the complete information on what you are trying to achieve. Rouighly i got that you are trying to set the value for textfield and bind the displayfield with textfield value.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayaprasad/qd0405zc/11/)**.

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.tip.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var parentPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            id: 'sampleform',
            border: false,
            padding: '5 0 0 0',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Theme Name',
                name: 'themeName',
                itemId: 'themeName',
                allowBlank: false,
                listeners: {
                    'change': function(textField, newVal, oldVal, opt) {
                        var displayField = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=Text]');
                        displayField[0].setValue(newVal);
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Text',
                itemId: 'themeText',
                name: 'Text',
                value: '<div class="theme-text-upload"></div>'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'populate Text Field',
                handler: function() {
                    var form = this.up('form');
                    var field = form.getForm();
                    var textField = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=themeName]');
                    textField[0].setValue("updated value");
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```